# read many lines with specific position

Tags: linux, unix, awk

Thank you for the time you soent reading it, maybe it is a nooby question 
I have a file of 10081 lines, this is an example of the file (a nordic seismic bulletin):

```
 2016  1 8 0921 21.5 L -22.382 -67.835 148.9  OSC 18 0.3 4.7LOSC                 1
 2016  1 8 1515 43.7 L -20.762 -67.475 188.7  OSC 16 .30 3.7LOSC                 1
 2016  1 9 0529 35.9 L -18.811 -67.278 235.9  OSC 16 0.5 3.9LOSC                 1
 2016  110  313 55.6 L -22.032 -67.375 172.0  OSC 14 .30 3.0LOSC                 1
 2016  110 1021 36.5 L -16.923 -66.668  35.0  OSC 16 0.4 4.5LOSC                 1
```

I tried the following code to extract some information from the file and save them in a separate file.

```
awk 'NR==1 {print substr($0,24,7), substr($0,32,7), substr($0,40,5)}' select.inp > lat_lon_depth.xyz
```

`substr($0,24,7)` means that I take from the 24th position 7 characters which is 
the latitude information (-22.382) and the same for the others (longitude from 32th place with 7 characters and depth on 4oth position with 5 characters).

So the question, is possible to go trought all the lines of file and have all latitude, longitude and depth. 
Thank you for the time

Comment: Get rid of `NR == 1` and it will process all the lines.

Comment: Dear @Barman, works perfect, thank you, dummy me

Comment: Alternately, since you know exactly the range of characters you need: `cut -c 24-44 select.inp`

Comment: dear @glennjackman, thank you it also works, but I have poblem, it reads from the 2nd line and skips the first line I tried `NR>=1` if i keep `NR==1` it only reads the first line, thank you in advance

Comment: dear @glennjackman and @Barman I added `if (NR>=1)` and then it works ok, thank you.